# Are Obligation, morality, .... combineable? (in the same character and for character generation)

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars-age-of-rebellion

As far as I have seen and read each of the 2 (3 with force&destiny) systems is using their own "drawback" part/system. Called for example obligation in edge of the empire, something else in age of rebellion and I think morality in force&destiny.

Now my question is twofold there:

1. Can these be combined (thus can a character have an obligation and the thing from age of rebellion)?
2. (if 1 is true) For character creation how is it handled there? As for example obligations can produce additional XP. Is it here possible to combine things thus take +10 XP from obligation and +10 XP from the aequivalent in age of rebellion to combine it to +20 XP at character creation (or +30 if force&destiny has a similar system)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it in a comment in the books.

You CAN have all 3 things (obligation, duty and morality) BUT
at character creation you can only benefit form modifying one (thus you have to choose
if you want to modify obligation, duty OR morality for additional xp,....). Still you can have all 3 with their apropriate effects during the game (only the mechanical character creation effects are limited to only 1 of them).

*The info is from out of the age of rebellion core rules book (as force & destiny and thus morality wasn't existing by that time it only mentioned obligation, but as the rules never contradicted between books so far in such regards I conclude there that it is the same with morality as it is with obligation and duty).*